# What is the category of Set-models of the category of finite sets?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{FSet}$ denote the category of finite sets.

If we consider $\mathbf{FSet}^\text{op}$ as a Lawvere theory, we recover the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets as its models. If, instead, we take as our theory $\mathbf{FSet}$ itself (this is not a Lawvere theory now I think, but it still is an algebraic theory), what is the category of models?

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the product-preserving functors from $\text{FinSet}$ to $\text{Set}$ are? Or, since as you say this is not a Lawvere theory, maybe the finite limit-preserving functors?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's another way to ask this. Although I was hoping that there is  a general recipe that compares models of a category $\mathcal{C}$ and models of $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ (when the category has enough structure, of course).

Comment: Oh I just saw your last question. No, I mean product-preserving functors.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{Set}^\text{op}$ is equivalent (by taking power sets) to the category of complete, atomic Boolean algebras.

In particular, $\mathbf{FinSet}^\text{op}$ is equivalent to the category of finite boolean algebras.

[nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/FinSet) has a page on **FinSet**. (and also on [CABA](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+Boolean+algebra)s)